# How to require subclass of abstract class as argument in a method

Tags: polymorphism, abstract-class, php-7.1

I am trying to create a hierarchy using PHP objects to compile-time error check that objects are of the correct type. Example:

```
abstract class ConfigObj {
    ...
}
abstract class Runner {
    public static abstract function buildWithConfig(ConfigObj $config);
}

class SpecificConfig extends ConfigObj {
    ...
}
class MainRunner extends Runner {
    public static function buildWithConfig(SpecificConfig $config){
        ...
    }
}
```

When this is attempted, PhpStorm complains that the `MainRunner` declaration of `buildWithConfig` must be compatible of that method in the `Runner` class, citing that apparently `SpecificConfig` cannot fill the role of `ConfigObj`. I could get around this by not declaring the type, but I would rather not as it would require extra processing to achieve the same type safety.

With Java, this use of polymorphism would be easy with generics. Is there an equivalent functionality in PHP that I have not come across yet?

Comment: This Q&A is a bit old, but I don't think PHP has changed much in this regard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553943/can-parameter-types-be-specialized-in-php/4554120#4554120

Comment: I think the answer here has a good example that shows why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802023/abstract-function-parameter-type-hint-overriding-in-php-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract function parameter type hint overriding in PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802023/abstract-function-parameter-type-hint-overriding-in-php-7)

Comment: If that answers your question sufficiently I can close this as a duplicate of it if you like.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I already voted as a duplicate. I didn't see the other post before, the language of describing the problem made it hard to Google effectively

Comment: Okay, just wanted to double check that's what you wanted before I closed it. And yeah, I definitely know what you mean about the language. :-)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed I can't close it by myself since it doesn't have a plain php tag. My gold badge only applies to that one. Well, added my vote anyway